# Xml serializer System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid when call web service method

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, serialization

I call a web service method passing a structured object with a series of data (string, date and decimal values) but I receive the seguent exception:

> There was an error generating the XML document.
>   System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterZMmWebserviceOrderInMiro.Write6_ZMmWebserviceOrderInMiro(Object o):    at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle)

I tried to do the serialization on a separate solution and it works fine in the same test environment. The data set used is the same.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry I can't post it. However the same code works fine on a separate solution with the same data. I can't debug directly the solution becouse my develop environment can't attach process on test environment.